# How to continue javascript execution when receiving errors during load

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

Not sure the best way to phrase the question, but suppose you are using jQuery to setup various things like so:

```
<script>

    function doSecond(){
        alert("Hi");
    }

    function dofirst(){
        var x = asdasd;
    }

    $(dofirst);
    $(doSecond);

</script>
```

So, imagine that dofirst and dosecond are completely independent. If dofirst throws an exception, which of course it will, then doSecond will never fire. I understand *why* this happens, but I'm wondering if there is a way of getting around this without having to wrap *EVERY* kind of jQuery handler that I want to set up in a try catch. E.g., I'd rather not do:

```
try{
 $(doFirst);
}
catch{
 //maybe log here?
}

try{
 $(doSecond);
}
catch{
 //maybe log here?
}
```

Now, if you're wondering why I want to do this? Well, take for example the code on the page you're looking at right now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#title').focus(function() { $('#how-to-tag').hide(); $('#how-to-format').hide(); $('#how-to-title').fadeIn('slow'); });
            $('#wmd-input').focus(function() { $('#how-to-tag').hide(); $('#how-to-format').fadeIn('slow'); $('#how-to-title').hide(); });
            $('#tagnames').focus(function() { $('#how-to-tag').fadeIn('slow'); $('#how-to-format').hide(); $('#how-to-title').hide(); });
        });
    </script>
```

Is it *really* necessary to have certain dom elements fade out when you click on them? No. But if you make a mistake in that function, then quite possibly other javascript that you really, really do need to run may never get setup.

Comment: The best way to do it is to have your code not throw exceptions. Page errors should always be treated as bugs, and fixed.

Comment: So the best solution is not make mistakes? +1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ways to ensure things run independently of each other:

- As you said, try/catch around each
- Call each in a setTimeout (or
  whatever the jQuery syntactic sugar
  is for that)
- Separate into different `<script>`
  blocks

Answer (score 1):

Obviously not ever throwing an exception is a ridiculous suggestion. Especially in the world of many browsers/versions/servers up/servers down. There are so many ways of website JS to break it's hard to find a site of any size which doesn't throw an exception of some type (on console examination).

You could create a simple wrapper (or extend existing jQuery methods)

```
function safeonload(fn){
   $(function(){
     try{
       fn();
     }catch{
        //log?
     }
   });
 }

 safeonload(doFirst);
 safeonload(doSecond);
```