# JavaScript process all errors in window.onerror

Tags: javascript, onerror

I am trying to process all errors in a page with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onerror = function (e, url, line) {
                var data = '{"error":"' + e + '","line":"' + line + '","uri":"' + url + '","client":"' + navigator.appName + '","version":"' + navigator.userAgent + '"}';
                var call = "http://myserver.com/sandbox/error.aspx?e=" + data;

                var jse = document.createElement("script");
                var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
                jse.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
                jse.setAttribute("src", call);
                head.appendChild(jse);
                alert("fail");
                return true;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var b;
            a = 5; //a is undefined
            b = 5;
            c = 8; //c is undefined
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This works, with the Internet Explorer developer tool (F12) i can see the request:

```
http://myserver.com/sandbox/jserror.aspx?e={"error":"'a' is undefined","line":"23","uri":"file:///C:/User/user/Desktop/Data/JSerror/javascript-error.htm","client":"Microsoft Internet Explorer","version":"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Zune 4.7)"}
```

The HTTP status is 200 OK, and the data is delivered to the server.
Problem is that only the first error gets processed, if i do this instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onerror = function (e, url, line) {
                var data = '{"error":"' + e + '","line":"' + line + '","uri":"' + url + '","client":"' + navigator.appName + '","version":"' + navigator.userAgent + '"}';
                var call = "http://myserver.com/sandbox/error.aspx?e=" + data;

                var jse = document.createElement("script");
                var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
                jse.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
                jse.setAttribute("src", call);
                head.appendChild(jse);
                alert("fail");
                return true;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var b;
            a = 5; //a is undefined
            b = 5;
         </script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            c = 8; //c is undefined
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then the first error from the first script tag and the first error from the second script tag is processed, i would like to process all errors, not just the first one from each script tag.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you left something out of your examples? Setting `a = 5;` and `c = 8;` without `var` isn't erroneous in either example. `a` and `c` will just be declared as globals, which they'd be anyways at that scope. However, trying to retrieve their value before declaring them would cause an exception.

Comment: Nope, the whole code is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with what your doing is 2 fold.

First to answer your question, any large error you would like to process will by it's nature stop the rest of the code from running. So if you would like to continue with your code after you handle an error you will need some type of callback function defined in your error handling.

So you could do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onerror = function (e, url, line) {
            var data = '{"error":"' + e + '","line":"' + line + '","uri":"' + url + '","client":"' + navigator.appName + '","version":"' + navigator.userAgent + '"}';
            var call = "http://myserver.com/sandbox/error.aspx?e=" + data;

            var jse = document.createElement("script");
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            jse.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            jse.setAttribute("src", call);
            head.appendChild(jse);
            alert("fail");
            return do_work(false);
        }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function do_work(bool){  
    if(bool == true){
        var b;
        a = 5; //a is undefined
        b = 5;
        c = 8; //c is undefined
   }else{
       //skip to new function since there was an error here!
   }
}
</script>
```

Or something along these lines.

The second is with your specific example.

```
 a = 5;
 c = 8;
```

Are not *actually* errors in javascript. If you fail to use `var` before declaring a variable it gets added to the global scope, you could in another script do this:

```
alert(window.a);  // would alert 5
```

The fact that IE is alerting you that `a` is `undefined` is a quark of IE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the function do_work(bool) is really not an option, i would like to be able to just include the error script at the top of my pages and log every message.

Comment: Then the answer stands that errors kill javascript so unless the user triggers a new javascript operation there won't *be* any more errors for you to process.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't continue execution once an error has been thrown, maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685106/how-to-continue-javascript-execution-when-receiving-errors-during-load) will help you solve your problem